# Amazon MWS Download orders Client

Tags: amazon-mws

We have a java client for downloading orders from Amazon MWS.

We use:
MaWSJavaClientLibrary-1.1.jar
MWSClientJavaRuntime-1.0.jar
MWSOrders_2013-09-01_v2020-10-20.jar

We download an xml with users data, with also shipping details (address, city, zipcode and so on...)

Begining from half 2020, we didn't receive customer name and address anymore. I mean that those 2 tags in xml were not passed anymore. We realized that something was changed in Amazon MWS for GDPR and security reasons.

We compiled a form online where we sent to amazon lots of informations about how we use those data.

However, we have not understand what we have to do in order to get those data again in xml.
Our client continues to work as usual, beu we continue to get xml without customer name and address.

Last email from amazon says:
Good morning,
thank you for your reply. As this issue is unrelated to your Developer Profile role assignments, we recommend that you review the information available in the links below for information on this topic.
Since the new API for Sales Partners (SP-API) is officially available, we are no longer issuing new credentials for MWS and are not updating existing MWS access roles. From now on, it is possible to develop applications in multiple regions with a single set of SP-API credentials.
More information on SP-API can be found here:
https://developer.amazonservices.it
SP-API documentation on GitHub: https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs
If you still need assistance on this topic, you can submit a MWS or SP-API technical support request here: https://developer.amazonservices.it/gp/mws/contactus.html
Thank you for selling with Amazon.

is there anyone that had same problem and can help us to retrieve those information again please?

Thanks

Comment: What marketplace(s) are you running this report for?

Comment: MWSOrders_2013-09-01_v2020-10-20.jar doesn't appear to be part of the official MWS client, is this something custom to your company? Could there be some code in there affecting the output?

Comment: Have you looked ar http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html to identify which specific orders report is being run by your code?